# Ajax posting to classic asp - how to wait for response?

Tags: ajax, asp-classic

I've got some code that calls via jQuery and Ajax an asp page to do an insert of a record. I think it's throwing errors, but I don't know how to "wait" out a response and only then redirect the client. Right now it fires the ajax and redirects. I don't know how to make a callback using ASP/Ajax to wait for the return.

```
/*   AJAX TUTORIAL SUBMIT ---------------------------------------- */
   function post_Tutorial_Submit(serial,critiqueText) {
     var jsonToSend={ serial: serial, critiqueText: critiqueText} ;
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'AJAX_Tutor_Tutorial_Submit.asp',
         data: jsonToSend,
         success: function(response) {
//            $("#spnSaveResponse").text(response);
         },
         error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
//            alert(xhr.responseText);
//            alert(thrownError);
         }
      }); // end ajax
   } // end post_tutorial_submit


   $( "#dialog-message-submit" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
                buttons: {
       "OK": function() {
          var critiqueText=$("#critique").val();
          var serial=$("#draft_serial").val();

          var response=post_Tutorial_Submit(serial,critiqueText);
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          window.location.href="../admin/admin_control.asp?message=submitted&serial="+serial;
       },
       Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
       }
       }
    }); //dialog
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your code in jQuery's `success: function(response) { ... }` callback.

Comment: thanks! I suppose I could put a function call in there. Why did I think it would be insanely more complicated??